# Is there a formal way of referring to the Somebody Else's Problem field, as described in the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy?

Tags: formality

For those who have not read the book in question, a Somebody Else's Problem field is typically a problem that is so unbelievable that its easier to just ignore it rather than to address it.

For example, the fact that we have discovered water on Mars has no real significance to the lives of so many people on Earth, yet its celebrated. So a person who walks into a scientists' congress asking this question would simply get ignored, like he had a Somebody Else's Problem field on him.

You can read the wikia on the field [here](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Somebody_Else's_Problem_field).

Comment: I'm not sure the SEP field applies only to unbelievable problems. I believe Douglas Adams meant this in a satirical way to refer to any problem most people prefer to ignore (e.g., to many people, others being homeless is "somebody else's problem" ).

Comment: @Tragicomic thanks, I knew I was missing on a more commonplace example!

Comment: I doubt there's a common term for this. Adams made up this phrase because there was no other way to refer to it.

Comment: Well, if there isn't one there definitely should be one! Its quite a common phenomenon!

Comment: An SEP field is like the one surrounding gun violence in the US.  This is much different from being ignored simply because you're acting like an idiot.  And there *is* a way to refer to this problem, it's "SEP field".

Comment: Douglas Adams once co-wrote a book (*"The meaning of Liff"*) that was essentially a dictionary of commonly-encountered concepts that didn't have ther own words (so place names were assigned to them instead). For example, the sensation of a sneeze that tickles but never actually becomes a sneeze was named an *"Amersham"* (after the rail station where the rails rattle but the trains never arrive.)

Comment: If the SEP should be of such magnitude that it really should be dealt with, but still people refuse to acknowledge it, it then becomes the **"elephant in the room"**.  Note the 'field' part of the phrase is referring to something generated by an imagined device that turns what should actually be an attractive spectacle (such as a spaceship in an incongrous location like Lord's cricket ground) into somebody else's problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's formal enough, if not quite capturing the [*dodging the issue*](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-cobuild/dodge%20the%20issue) sense, so I'd suggest 
[**Demarcation**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/demarcation):

> British: The practice of requiring that specific jobs be assigned to
>   members of particular trade unions. (-- Oxford Dictionaries)

If you've ever seen [*I'm All Right Jack*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%27m_All_Right_Jack) you'll get the idea: the refusal to carry out a task as it must be part of someone else's *job*.  In theory it's about solidarity and not wanting to undermine your fellow worker's employment. Whereas in reality, you might detect a hint of self-interest...

(EDIT: of course 'demarcation' is what is given as the *excuse* for the behaviour, rather than the behaviour itself, but I think the relevance stands).

Comment: If you've seen*/read/heard the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy you should be familiar with the idea of **Demarcation** from the two trade unionist philosophers arguing against the construction of the computer, Deep Thought: *"I'll tell you what the problem is, mate - demarcation! The search for the meaning of life is clearly the prerogative of your working philosopher! What's the point of us staying up all night arguing whether there is (or isn't) an Ultimate Being if this machine comes along and gives you his phone number in the morning?!"*

Comment: * - not sure if this exchange was in the movie, but it was in the book, the BBC TV Series and the BBC radio series.

Comment: It's been a while, but now you mention it I do remember, thanks. Nice reference.

Comment: I've never heard the word being used in that context. Do you think I could use it in this context: "While everyone agrees that we would be better placed to serve our clients if we understood their products, target customers, pricing strategies and so forth, no one really does anything to bridge the gap." ? Maybe I could refer to the "imaginary line of demarcation that restricts service providers from crossing into the minds of the service receivers"?